# Render image phantomjs and save amazons3

Tags: amazon-s3, phantomjs, rendering

I would like to render a screenshot from PhantomJS (no Node.js - just javascript) in a cloud environment and save it on Amazon S3. So someone has any idea how could I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: https://phantomjscloud.com/site/index.html

Comment: Thanks! Chris, but I already have a system, not use another.